# Hadoop MapReduce Total Sort Word Count

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to do a total sort in mapreduce Word Count.

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf(), "wordcount");
  job.setJarByClass(this.getClass());
  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
  job.setMapperClass(Map.class);

  //Total Sort
  job.setPartitionerClass(TotalOrderPartitioner.class);
  InputSampler.Sampler<Text, IntWritable> sampler = new InputSampler.RandomSampler<Text, IntWritable>(0.1, 10000, 10);
  InputSampler.writePartitionFile(job, sampler);
  Path inputDir = new Path(args[2] + "/_tmp");
  Path partitionFile = new Path(inputDir, "_partitioning");
  TotalOrderPartitioner.setPartitionFile(job.getConfiguration(),partitionFile);
  InputSampler.writePartitionFile(job, sampler);

  job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
  job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);  

  return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

But i got error like `java.io.IOException: wrong key class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable`

I don't understand how InputSampler.RandomSampler work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code there is no `InputFormat` set for the job, so default will be taken which is `TextInputFormat<LongWritable,Text>`.

For `InputSampler.RandomSampler<Text, IntWritable>` it has been configured as *Text, IntWritable* which doesn't match with `TextInputFormat`.

Since there is type mismatch between `InputFormat` and `InputSampler` the error is thrown.